# get gravity form ID from backend/wordpress admin

Tags: plugins, actions, plugin-gravity-forms

I want to add a filter to a form submission
[like it is done here](https://gravitywp.com/capitalize-fields-in-gravity-forms/).

```
add_action('gform_pre_submission_6', 'capitalize_fields_6');
function capitalize_fields_6($form){
    // Code here
}
```

My question is, how do you get the form ID on the WP admin side?  Where is the number 6 coming from to access the form in the action?

Comment: If you look at the list of Forms (*Forms > Forms*) in the back end there's a column that tells you the ID.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You are correct.  I'm new to the plugin and was had tunnel vision in the notifications/confirmations tabs :)  If you answer I can select it.

Comment: Also, if you want to dynamically get a form ID for a form titled 'My Contact Form', you can use this class method to obtain it: `RGFormsModel::get_form_id('My Contact Form')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the list of Forms (Forms > Forms) in the back end there's a column that tells you the ID. You can also get it from the top of the screen when editing a form. Next to the form's Title there's an orange box that says "ID: 6".

Answer (score 1):

[image: 3 ways you get view gravity form ID]

There are 3 ways you can view the gravity form ID

1. Via inspect element - when you are viewing the page were the gravity form is embedded. Right click on the form and choose Inspect element.
2. When you are editing a specific form. It's on top highlighted with color orange.
3. When you are viewing all the forms. A columns names such as ID, ENTRIES, VIEWS.